# Why is geom_freqpoly creating a fake minimum datapoint?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The minimum observation in my data is 326. But `geom_freqpoly` plots a frequency polygon that starts *below zero*. What gives? And how do I make it start in a sensible place?

```
min(diamonds$price)
# [1] 326
qplot(price, data=diamonds, geom="freqpoly")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the origin argument:

```
qplot(price, data=diamonds, geom="freqpoly", origin=0)
```

[image]

geom_freq poly() is by default figuring out the polygon to make using the same stat_bin() function that geom_histogram() uses. You can get more information on different valid arguments for controlling the density estimate from `?stat_bin()`